# Phalcon 1.2.4 in IIS

Tags: php, iis, phalcon

I'm triying to use Phalcon 1.2.4 on IIS

My Environment:
WindowsServer08 R2 x64
IIS 7 + PHP FastCGI + URL Rewrite

When i follow:

Official Tutorial 1

I can run IndexController but I can't run SingupController

![enter image description here][1]

It's always getting a 404 Error

If I change my Environment to XAMPP & Copy My Tutorial Project . It can be executed on XAMPP without any issues.

Does Phalcon support IIS?

Comment: What tutorial is that?

Comment: Phalcon doesn't run on IIS, you need Apache, Nginx or Cherokee.

Comment: Rowland ~ my study tutorial is http://goo.gl/ZehvcK  : )

Comment: dciso ~ but i'm try use CakePhp on IIS , It's can running .
       is Phalcon not support IIS ?  so sad : (

Comment: @dciso Phalcon version 1.2.4 does seem run on IIS as PHP extension. I'm testing it right now in a test environment (IIS 8.0, PHP 5.4). The [INVO sample application](http://blog.phalconphp.com/post/20928554661/invo-a-sample-application) works, but I haven't tested anything more advanced though.

Comment: @JanReilink Hi ,i see you metion you testing Phalcon 1.2.4 ON IIS 8 by use PHP 5.4 , Can you teach me how do it? i am use Phalcon 1.2.4 On IIS 7 and PHP 5.4 , But The INVO  sample i can't run , when i click another link, it's always getting Http Error 404 , can't find the file. Thanks  you : )

Comment: @KingJk I did nothing more than loading up the PHP extension in the php.ini, and place the INVO sample on my test website. If my memory serves me correctly, it *has to be* in a sub directory /invo. Also you need to have Helicon Ape or ISAPI_Rewrite 3 installed to process the .htaccess file, or import them into IIS URL Rewrite module

Comment: @JanReilink Thanks u reply , I'm follow your tips , and try to build INVO sample on IIS .I'm put INVO sample in wwwroot and Import Rewrite rule by use URL Rewrite module. But it's always get ERROR 404 This is my Config File [ConfigFile](http://goo.gl/LXB9k3) Please help me ,very Appreciated for you help : )

Comment: @KingJk what does your directory structure look like and in which directory did you place the web.config file?

Comment: @JanReilink Thanks u reply again .This is my INVO Project . [INVO](http://goo.gl/fjc16j) . and in Project web.config is my URL Rewrite RUle , could can help again ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, i follow these steps.

1. put `web.config` file from http://www.sitepoint.com/phalcon-windows-azure/  on public folder
2. edit index.php from public folder and add
   `//Setup a base URI so that all generated URIs include the "tutorial" folder
   $di->set('url', function(){
       $url = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
       $url->setBaseUri('/example1/public/');
       return $url;
   });`

   note that i have this example on a directory called example1, ie `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\example1`
3. visit `http://localhost/example1/public/`